# URL Masking filenames from URLs using core PHP

Tags: php, url

I want to hide filenames (URL masking).

These are the URL's I have with my project:

```
http://example.com/add_candidate.php?id=12
http://example.com/admin/access_author.php
http://example.com/associate/support/edit_profile.php?a_id=10
```

My URLs should URLs look like:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/admin/
http://example.com/associate/support/
```

How is this possible?

Comment: htaccess is what you are looking for

Comment: You should better use a framework like codeigniter to do that

Comment: I dnt knw codeigniter I did my whole project in core PHP only. should I knw any possibility with core PHP

Comment: Or if you're looking for a more advanced method of handling URLs' try a router, Slim 3 is a simple framework you can check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a php issue. :)

If you are using Apache HTTP server, you may want to take a look at `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite`. They are Apache features that map a server URL into a PHP script.
For example:

```
http://example.com/associate/support/
```

to

```
http://example.com/associate/support/edit_profile.php?a_id=10
```

Here's a nice tutorial on how to accomplish that:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Answer (score 0):

You can plug in any routing Library. Personally, I find Bramus Router (https://github.com/bramus/router) quite easy to integrate into existing projects.

First, you create a .htaccess file at the root of your project like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This makes Apache pass all requests to the index.php file where we then define our routes like this:

```
// Static route: /hello
$router->get('/hello', function () {
    echo '<h1>bramus/router</h1><p>Visit <code>/hello/<em>name</em></code> to get your Hello World mojo on!</p>';
});
```